# Can you use AWS CodeArtifact as PowerShell module repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-codeartifact

I would like to use AWS CodeArtifact as a repository for PowerShell modules.
I want to be able to use Register-PSRepository to register the repo, Publish-Module to publish and Install-Module to install etc.

I have the NuGet URL for my repo, but I can't get it to work with the Register-PSRepository
command. I can't find any documentation for this.

I have tried using an URL like this: https://mydomain-myaccountid.d.codeartifact.myregion.amazonaws.com/nuget/myrepo/v3/index.json
I have tried using an access key/secret as credentials for the Register-PSRepository.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so, how do you do this?